# NullPointerException in Jasper Reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

When I export a report using jasper report (version 1.2.4), it throws NPE. And I cant find any solution to the problem online. Can anyone help me in this regard please?

If I remove one problematic column in my report and export it, it exports fine. Couldn't find whats the problem with that column as it contains large data.

Many Thanks in Advance !

Posting the exception below :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException|

at java.awt.font.TextLayout.getBaselineFromGraphic(Unknown Source)|

at java.awt.font.TextMeasurer.initAll(Unknown Source)|

at java.awt.font.TextMeasurer.<init>(Unknown Source)|

at java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.<init>(Unknown Source)|

at java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.<init>(Unknown Source)|

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.renderParagraph(TextMeasurer.java:259)|

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.measure(TextMeasurer.java:220)|

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextElement.chopTextElement(JRFillTextElement.java:528)|

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.prepare(JRFillTextField.java:501)|

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:345)|

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:311)|

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:275)|

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:1291)|

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:631)|

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportContent(JRVerticalFiller.java:248)|

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:132)|

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:750)|

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:666)|

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:89)|

at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:601)
```

Comment: We can't either, because we have no idea what the column is, what its type is, or... anything.

Comment: Can you post your code? Are you using report template (`jrxml` file)?

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ That column contains just file and folder names.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the exact same error using pure JRE code, like this:

```
@Test
public void testText()
{
    String text = "\uFFFF\u0300";
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(text);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textArea);
}
```

Because of this, I have been assuming it's a JRE bug and already submitted it to Oracle. The workaround is presumably to cull whatever character sequence is causing it, but I obviously don't know what you are feeding in.

Comment: +1 good catch :-) You might consider adding the bug/report number and maybe for which chars sequences this happens.

Comment: They haven't given me a bug number yet, and the char sequence *we* found is in the example. I don't know the complete set of char sequences where it happens.

Comment: Just following up that as usual, Oracle dropped my bug report on the floor, never confirming it nor giving me any kind of tracking number to follow it up.

Comment: I encountered this problem also years ago but have forgotten to submit a bug report. At least there seems to be one now (from 2014-03-20): https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8037965

Answer (score 0):

This is likely either (1) a bug in the version of the JRE you're using, or (2) a threading bug. We've had the same top five lines in stack traces in a project I work on.